# Dynamically created templates with Polymer in a Chrome app

Tags: javascript, polymer, google-chrome-app, content-security-policy

I'm working on a Chrome app which needs to do two main things:

1. Automatically generate a UI from a list of fields and data types provided by an attached device.
2. Allow users to define and share their own presentation for the UI and automatically apply that presentation when the device is attached.

I'm using Polymer, and I figure the best way to achieve #2 is with user-provided Polymer elements. Then, I can simply bind the variables from the device to the UI, and the user's template can determine how to display and style them.

Achieving #1, then, is a matter of automatically generating a polymer element from an input schema. This is somewhat different from the usual approach, where I'd presumably define a repeated template with conditional child templates for each type of widget.

My questions, then, are:

1. How can I dynamically evaluate a polymer element/template from a remote source without violating the Chrome App's CSP, and without introducing significant XSS issues? (Hopefully, the former protects me from the latter?)
2. What's the easiest way to dynamially generate markup for a Polymer element? Can I define a meta-template and use the generated markup?

Comment: I don't have full answers for your questions here, but for #2 I noticed this thread today - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/polymer-dev/ioVhx4Ynv4M/5iiEnPVBrIMJ & thought it might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure why you rule out using a pre-defined Polymer element with (admittedly, complicated) `<template>` logic in it, but if you're sure that you need things to be dynamic and generate the element's content on the fly while still making use of Polymer's data binding, then `injectBoundHTML()` might be what you're looking for.

It's unfortunately not documented at the moment, but there are examples of how to use it in the [open issue tracking the documentation](https://github.com/Polymer/docs/issues/607).

You can fetch the "bound" HTML from any source, and while I'm not an expert on CSP, I don't believe that it will trigger any additional CSP consideration.

Comment: The only reason I ruled it out is because I want to be able to generate a default template that users can then edit for their particular device - rather than having to write one from scratch in order to perform any customisation at all.

Comment: It's a little unclear to me if/when `injectBoundHTML` is required. The Polymer manual section on [dynamic imports](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/helpers.html#using-dynamic-html-imports) shows a way to inject an element using Javascript, and it doesn't seem to do any special handling to get the elements upgraded. When is and isn't this necessary?

Comment: I haven't played around with dynamic imports much, but I guess that's another option, yeah. You could theoretically have a bunch of different HTML files that each had a different definition of what your `<custom-element>` was, and then import the appropriate one for each user. It's just a different approach to using a single "shell" element definition whose shadow DOM was populated at runtime via a network fetch and `injectBoundHTML()`.

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant to link to [imperative registration](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#imperativeregister), which shows that simply setting `innerHTML` seems to be enough to get Polymer to recognise new elements - which makes me wonder why you need `injectBoundHTML` at all.

Comment: I believe the main distinction between `.innerHTML` and `injectBoundHTML()` is covered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433389 and has to do with dynamically modifying existing elements rather than registering new elements. If you want to register new elements then presumably  dynamic imports or setting `.innerHTML` would work.